# Change all inputs with readonly attribute to disabled instead using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with my jQuery syntax.  Could someone show me how to iterate through all controls on a form that have the readonly attribute, remove the readonly attribute, and make then disabled instead?  Thank you.

Comment: How about posting what you have so far instead of asking someone to write your code for you?

Comment: You're right.  I'll make sure to do so next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[readonly="readonly"]').removeAttr("readonly").prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#formID").each('input[readonly="readonly"]', function () {                
       $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
       $(this).attr("disabled", true);
 });
```

Not sure if you are doing this on page load, or on a link/button click, but this is a start.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_form_id [readonly]').removeAttr("readonly").prop("disabled",true);
```